# Access 2013 design report for tow table

Tags: database, report, ms-access-2013

I have two tables Main, and Department

### Main Table

issue_id
observation
action
date
close Yes/No

### Department Table

id (auto increment)
issue_id
Department name

I want to create a report that display the issue from Main table and then display all department that have relation to the issue.

I tried to do it, it display the issue and then one department then display the same issue with different department

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a group in your Report Designer. 
Refer to the image below where hilighted.

Add your Issue_Id column as a group.
Display your Issue_Id information in the group section and the Department information in the details section.

[image]